# How can i get rid of this error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure assignhousekeeping, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 57] Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a trigger code to insert a data to cleaning table when a new data is inserted in condos table. this is the code that I have written:

```
create trigger assignhousekeeping
on condos
after insert
as
    insert into CLEANING(Condo#, DateCleaned, HKID)
        value(
            (select Condo# from inserted),
            getdate(),
            (select PID
             from PERSONNEL
             where FName = 'janice'
               and LName = 'avery'));
```

After running this I get these error messages:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure assignhousekeeping, > Line 6 [Batch Start Line 57]
> Incorrect syntax near 'value'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure assignhousekeeping, > Line 8 [Batch Start Line 57]
> Incorrect syntax near ','.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure assignhousekeeping, > Line 13 [Batch Start Line 57]
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

and the trigger did not go off as well. How can I fix this?

Comment: Aside from the broken logic, the keyword is `VALUES` not `VALUE`

Answer (score 1):

The correct `insert` syntax uses `values` not `value`.  However, that is only the beginning of your problems, because the trigger assumes that `inserted` has only one row.

I can speculate that you actually want:

```
insert into CLEANING (Condo#, DateCleaned, HKID)
    select Condo#, getdate(), p.pid
    from inserted i left join
         PERSONNEL p
         on p.FName = 'janice' and LName = 'avery';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was the "values" not "value" after that everything worked just fine!

Comment: @AlexJ Nope - your posted code will generate an error when more than one row is affected by a single statement. Someone will eventually find that error.

Comment: @SMor would the code written by Gordon Linoff work better on the circumstances where more than one row is affected by a single statement?

Comment: @AlexJ . . . Yes, the code fixes the bug in your code just waiting to happen.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you! I guess I was not thinking that far enough.

Comment: @AlexJ . . . I really wish SQL Server would detect this sort of logic and return an error.  At the very least, the document should start with the advice to test on an insert with multiple rows for *all* triggers.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I agree the documentation should call this common gotcha. Note we are all empowered to edit the doc page and submit a pull request.

Comment: @DanGuzman In such a query (selecting a scalar value from a table expression), the plan will have an `Assert` to prevent multiple rows. IMO *any* case of an `Assert` in that position is a bug in the query, as it should have a `TOP 1`, therefore there should be an option to return an error or warning in such cases

Comment: @Charlieface, we are all also empowered to submit [SQL Server feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server) for product improvements.

Comment: @DanGuzman [Much](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32890519) [luck](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32897728) [it has](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32889145) [got](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35750854) [so far](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32902852) [for simple](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/34895971) [suggestions](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32647648)

Comment: @DanGuzman ... and [that site is being discontinued](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/uservoice-pages-430e1a78-e016-472a-a10f-dc2a3df3450a)